# htaccess url mapping to a sub-folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

thanks for taking the time to read my question.

My Objective:
I have 50 domains and each domain will have a page or an entire website under "/gallery" e.g:
domain1.com/gallery
domain2.com/gallery

and all the website that will be displayed when someone visited the URL "*/gallery" of any domain will actually see the content of a website from my WordPress Multisite install and on this WPMU I have 50 sites as well and each site has a unique Domain Mapped for e.g:
site1 is mapped to domain1.com/gallery
site2 is mapped to domain2.com/gallery

**So my main goal is to do this:**
Build an htaccess file that can Mapp domain1.com/gallery to "/app/wordpress/" (a subfolder on the domain root):
So every request to domain*.com/gallery will display the content from /app/wordpress/ on the same folder where that domain is pointed.

Note:

1. Wordpress MU is installed in a folder and that folder is shared as "Symlinks" so every website has a folder named "app/wordpress".
2. The code I will produce will be placed on each folder of each domain.
3. Since Wp MU is installed in a Symlinks folder then it's accessible from "domain*.com/app/wordpress" from any domain but I need to change that to "domain*.com/gallery"
4. The kinda mapping I'm talking about is to rewrite the URL from "domain*.com/app/wordpress" to "domain*.com/gallery" with all the urls on that website as well.

Thanks and sorry for the long explanation. 
Have a nice day.

Comment: I guess to make it simple I want to: rewrite the URLs from "domain*.com/app/wordpress" to "domain*.com/gallery" with all the URLs within those websites.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to include research you have done that doesn't meet your needs or code you have tried that didn't work, and why you know that it didn't work. See more advice on how to ask a good question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).